# How to override ChakraUI default background color with an image

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm just starting to use Chakra UI and I'm thoroughly confused with how to override their default themes. Specifically the background image. When I add the ChakraProvider to my main app, it sets a default white background to the page's body, and it ignores my own background image I set in my App.css
Does someone know how to override this?

App.css

```
body {
    background-image: url("./images/forest.jpg");

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS={false}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            <div>
              *routes here*
            </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is what the inspector shows on the webpage. The ones marked with *strikethrough* are the ones being ignored. If uncheck the background property that chakra-ui provides by default with the white color, my background image then appears

```
body {
    font-family: var(--chakra-fonts-body);
    color: var(--chakra-colors-gray-800);
    background: var(--chakra-colors-white);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    line-height: var(--chakra-lineHeights-base);
}
body {
    background-image: url(/static/media/forest.04032f88.jpg); *strikethrough*
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center; *strikethrough*
    background-size: cover; *strikethrough*
}
```

Comment: put "!important" at the end. eg:- `background-image: url("./images/forest.jpg") !important;`

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't used that before, so I really never knew about it, you can put it as the answer so i can mark it

Comment: done, added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put "!important" at the end. eg:- `background-image: url("./images/forest.jpg") !important;`